# Can unstable PWM timing be corrected?

Tags: gpio, pwm

I would like to set the motor speed of a RPLidar A3 which requires a 25 kHz PWM. So I played around with the following:

```
from RPi import GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(12, 1000)
pwm.start(50)
```

Unfortunately, it seems the frequency is not 1 kHz, but 873 Hz and the jitter is HUUUUGGGE. With `htop` I make sure my RPI is very idle.

Last but not least, I cannot get a 25 kHz PWM, the highest seems to be 7.2 kHz.

Is that normal?

[image]

Comment: Pi.GPIO is updated with hardware PWM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pigpio supports DMA timed PWM on GPIO 0-31.  This has restricted frequencies and resolution.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_frequency

pigpio also drives hardware PWM on GPIO 12, 13, 18, and 19. This is more flexible and accurate.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM

There are different function calls for the two types of PWM.

Comment: Where did you get this info?

Comment: Added links to the Python API.

Comment: Damned! I've found this website before, but I thought it wasn't about RPI because of the URL name and the vintage look :)

Comment: @nowox pigpio is really useful, but my eyes see Pig Pi O not the intended Pi GPIO.  Maybe yours did something similar.

Comment: I pronounce it pig pee oh.

Comment: @joan then I'm not so odd, and was wrong about the intention, though pig pie comes to my mind more readily than pig pee!

Comment: @ChrisH Actually you are correct to say the name was for Pi GPIO which conveniently expresses its function.  It's just I have always written it as pigpio and internally pronounced it as pig-pee-oh.

Answer (score 2):

RPi.GPIO only has software PWM - which by its nature is imprecise.

`pigpio` has hardware timed PWM which is better (and also hardware PWM if you look hard enough).

bcm2835 has hardware PWM and so does WiringPi (but it is deprecated).

My clone of RPi.GPIO (Pi.GPIO) now has hardware PWM in the final stages of testing expected to be released in the next few days.

**Pi.GPIO is updated** and can be downloaded :-

git clone https://github.com/Milliways2/Pi.GPIO.git

---

The following code produces the trace below. (The BitScope is a bit slow to capture edges).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""
"""
import sys, os, time
import Pi.GPIO as GPIO

PWM0=12
PWM1=13

# Pi3 & earlier have 19.2MHz clock
# DIVIDER=15  # gives a precise 10kHz signal
# RANGE=128

# Pi4 has 54MHz clock
# DIVIDER=36 # gives a precise 10kHz signal
# RANGE=150
DIVIDER=45 # gives a precise 10kHz signal
RANGE=120

def main():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.pwm_setmode(0)
    GPIO.pwm_setClock(DIVIDER)

    GPIO.pwm_setGpio(PWM0)
    GPIO.pwm_setGpio(PWM1)

    GPIO.pwm_setmode(GPIO.PWM_MODE_MS)

    GPIO.pwm_setRange(PWM1, RANGE)
    GPIO.pwm_Write(PWM1, RANGE//4)   # duty cycle of 25%

    GPIO.pwm_setRange(PWM0, RANGE)
    GPIO.pwm_Write(PWM0, RANGE//2)   # duty cycle of 50%


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: PWM 50kHz]

Comment: Why is the RPI.GPIO not using the hardware PWM by default? I just noticed the `pigpio` requires the daemon `pigpiod` to be started. It looks cumbersome, isn't?

Comment: Also it seems with `pi.set_PWM_frequency(12, 25000)` I only get `8000`. Is this the maximum?  I don't find this information in the BCM2711 datasheet.

Comment: @nowox You would have the developer of RPI.GPIO, as for pigpio - yes you do need the daemon. I thought it would be relatively simple to add hardware PWM, but 2 months later I am forced to revise that opinion; the documentation is obtuse.

Comment: @nowox I have been running hardware PWM  at 10 kHz for a couple of months (in c code) it is just the python which is causing me problems. There is no reason you can't run at a couple of MHz (although you lose resolution). It would only take a few minutes to test @ 100kHz but not tonight, it is already past bedtime.

Comment: I feel this is a good and reasonable answer, but I take issue with the claim that `wiringPi` is [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation). AIUI, the original developer (Gordon) no longer supports `wiringPi`, but: **1)** `wiringPi` still runs well on current RPi hardware, firmware & software releases, and **2)** the [`wiringPi` library remains available through GitHub](https://github.com/WiringPi), and is supported by a team that has assumed Gordon's role.

Comment: @Seamus The **author** says so; there is a half-baked attempt to resurrect it - which last time I looked was incomplete and had errors. The (Unofficial Mirror for WiringPi bindings) was never supported by the author and he warned against its use. I even tried to make my own version, but the code is convoluted and frankly contains a lot of historical crud. Unfortunately Gordon never released the source for the last version. Feel quite free to use it on existing hardware & OS. It remains to be seen if it is ever included in Bullseye.

Comment: Yes - he does make that claim, but it's inconsistent with most definitions of the word "deprecated". There are innumerable cases in which the original author abandons a project he started, which is taken over by others... This is a ***fork*** - not a deprecation. As for your claim of being "half-baked", I'm sure you intend that to be your opinion, and **not** a statement of fact.

Comment: I agree... I only commented because I felt that repeating an inaccurate claim (re deprecation) detracted from an otherwise good answer. It has nothing to do with  the software really - it's simply inaccurate English.

Answer (score 1):

As [Milliways](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/8697/milliways) said, you (me) are using the Python GPIO library which uses software emulated PWM, not the hardware PWM.

The easiest solution would be in you case to load the PWM overlay.

```
dtoverlay pwm pin=12 func=4
```

Then export a new PWM channel

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/export
```

You can now set the period and the duty-cycle:

```
echo 40000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/period
echo 10000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/duty_cycle 
echo 1 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/enable
```

What you have is what you want:

[image]

Comment: The `sysfs` interface is deprecated (although it is unlikely to disappear soon). The PWM is undocumented, and I have always been deterred by "Currently the clock must have been enabled and configured by other means" which is undefined.

Comment: If you are happy to use the command line interface, you would be better to use PIGS, which is documented and far more flexible. It works well for PWM.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method is to use a PWM HAT (Adafruit does one - but it seems  not to work well with DC Servos) instead of using a RPi. This virtúally guarantees good timing and much less "strain" on the RPi.